# Termination Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu

I have serious problem regarding logging to my laptop desktop, since I agreed to upgrade my Ubuntu OS and for some reasons I had to cancel this process and shut down my laptop immedietely.

As I started to power on my laptop, I found only this results that shown in the attached photo. This result stays for very very very long time and I do not know what I have to do ;(((

Please I need some advices and recommendations for this miserable results.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1iDv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a recovery mode on ubuntu. You can repair broken packages. I suggest this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iSRFBuDDgU. Also I couldn't see any problem on image you attached.